# AngularJS - How to force a ng-model of a range input to be null?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input

It is a filter, with two input's using the same ng-model simultaneously:

```
<!-- Number input --> 
<input
type="number"
maxlength="5"
step="0.25"
min="-10"
max="10"
placeholder="0.00"
ng-model="sphere">

<!-- Range Input -->
<input type="range" ng-model="sphere" min="-10" max="10" step="0.25">
```

**Goal:**

- Initially show the placeholder instead of the value, which is set up by the range input.

**Issues:**

- Range input can't be set to Null.

**Possbile solutions**

- Activate range input and it's effects on the ng-model variable only when focused either value is changed from Null to an valid numberic value.

[image: This image shows how it is set up, where the white bar is the au]

This image shows how it is set up, where the white bar is the auxiliary range input

I am looking for any kind of tip that could lead to a solution, I believe, if it is ever possible to achieve, that would be by activating the range input on change. However, ´disabled´ and ´readonly´ don't do that, what could do ?

I am trying to let it work this way, once I want to implement, ng-masks, where placeholders are important at this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `input` element inside a `form`, give the input a name and then you can check the state of the `input` (e.g. `formName.inputName.$touched`).

Based on the state of the `input` element, you can show/hide different content. So the value would only show when the `input` has been touched.